# Wrong color with hsb color series in xelatex

Tags: xetex, color, colortbl

I tried to use hsb color series provided by `xcolor` package in the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
% example one
\definecolorseries{test}{hsb}{step}{blue}[hsb]{.041667,0,0}% 1/24
\resetcolorseries[12]{test}%
\rowcolors[\hline]{1}{test!!+}{test!!+}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\
\number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\
\number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\
\number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\
\end{tabular}
% example two
\definecolorseries{test}{hsb}{step}{blue}[hsb]{.0416667,0,0}% 1/24
\resetcolorseries[12]{test}%
\rowcolors[\hline]{1}{test!!+}{test!!+}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\
\number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\
\number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\
\number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

But when compiling it with `xelatex`, I found the 9th color in the second example was wrong. It's ok when compiling with `pdflatex`. The only difference between these two examples was the step size. What's the problem in it?

[image]

Comment: It’s OK when compiled with `luatex` too.

Comment: Why `{.041667,0,0}` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following line in your preamble

```
\substitutecolormodel{hsb}{rgb}
```

From the `xcolor` documentation on `\substitutecolormodel`'s usage:

> Example: assume the actual driver has an incorrect implementation of `hsb` whereas
>   `rgb` looks well. Then `\substitutecolormodel{hsb}{rgb}` could be a good choice,
>   since it converts — from that point onwards — all definitions of `hsb` colors by
>   `xcolor`'s algorithms into `rgb` specifications, without touching other models.

Also take a look at subsection 5.4 'A remark on accuracy' of the manual.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\substitutecolormodel{hsb}{rgb}
\begin{document}
% example one
\definecolorseries{test}{hsb}{step}{blue}[hsb]{.041667,0,0}%
\resetcolorseries[12]{test}%
\rowcolors[\hline]{1}{test!!+}{test!!+}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\
\number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\
\number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\
\number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\
\end{tabular}
% example two
\definecolorseries{test}{hsb}{step}{blue}[hsb]{.0416667,0,0}%
\resetcolorseries[12]{test}%
\rowcolors[\hline]{1}{test!!+}{test!!+}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\
\number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\
\number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\
\number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\ \number\rownum\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]